# Angular 6 CORS with XSRF on Net.Core not requesting all headers

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, angular6

I know we have a lot of questions similar to this one, but I tried all, and seems like my problem is a little bit different.

as all others questions, I have a client (localhost:XXXX) making request on my Api(localhost:YYYY)

the problem came, I guess, because I'm also using XSRF, and probably the default CORS middleware are not allowing all headers, but only the requested headers

I figured out, that sometimes, randomly, the client side request came with the XSRF request, and then the server return the header allowing it, but it's really random.

Ex:

Request:

1 => Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization

2 => Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization, XSRF-TOKEN

Response

1 => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization

2 => Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization, XSRF-TOKEN

I was expecting, that when I set `opt.AllowAnyHeader()`, the response should return `always Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *`, but looks like it will only return the headers requested.

so, it's something I should do on Angular side to request all the headers?( I really don't like this Idea), I'm doing something wrong on the API side? or should I just go and create my own middleware to handle CORS(I also think it's not a good Idea) ?

On my Api, I set

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        this.AddDependencyInjection(services);

        if (this.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableCors", false))
        {
            services.AddCors();
        }

        this.ConfigureAuth(services);

        services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
        {
            options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";
        });
  // ...
  }

    // ...
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IAntiforgery antiforgery)
    {
        if (this.Configuration.GetValue<bool>("EnableCors", false))
        {
            app.UseCors(opt => opt
                .AllowAnyHeader()
                .AllowAnyMethod()
                .AllowAnyOrigin()
                .AllowCredentials()
                );
        }

        app.Use(next => context =>
        {
            if (string.Equals(context.Request.Path.Value, "/token", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            {
                var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
                context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });
            }

            return next(context);
        });


// ...
  }
```

and on Angular side, I have:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClientXsrfModule
  ],
  providers: [
    httpInterceptorProviders,
    AuthService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

I'm playing with auth and CORS, so all my code are basically proof of concept codes and I can share if needed, but I guess this is enough.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question: What exactly is the problem that you're observing here?

Comment: if you are trying this in Chrome then there is a bug/feature that prevents CORS headers from working properly with localhost. You cannot test it on local host. You can install some extension that will add headers on the fly but it's just a hack. CORS has to be tested with real domain names...

Comment: @PavelAgarkov do you have a link for this bug/feature?

Comment: @KirkLarkin I'm expecting that my client side request all the headers I need, or my API side allow all the headers I need, but currently, my client side only request for one header, and my API side only allow exactly the headers the client requested, and not all the headers that the response have